# ArcGIS Server WFS Error and Consumption

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, wfs, ogc, arcgis-enterprise

I have a WFS Service I publish from ArcGIS Server.  I have used several clients to test and the service either does not display the geometry or it just throws an error.   The layer shows up in the TOC, I can access, and in some cases I can get to the attributes.  The ArcGIS MAP Service will load fine and I get geometry and attributes correctly.   Once I do that, I can find the geometry of the WFS, but it is off in a totally different area and rotated 90 degrees.   The MAP Service and WFS are the same, published with WFS capabilities set when I publish the .mxd.  MAP Service OK, WFS an issue...

When I load the service into ArcGIS Portal it seems to display fine.    Unfortunately, that is just a test and clients need to get at the service through WFS without ArcGIS Portal.

When I view in Bentley/GAIA/GRASS/QGIS, and others, I get a different error.   Again, the layers show up in TOC in all of the products I have tested but throw various errors or totally skewed geometry.

Here is an error I get in QGIS when I test it for example.

```
Layer xxxxxxx.GRID_SPACING_MAP: Download of features for layer 
Bentley_SpacingMap:xxxxxx.GRID_SPACING_MAP failed or partially failed: Download of features failed: 
Error downloading:
https://xxxxxxxxx/arcgis/services/xxxxxxx/SpacingMap/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=xxxxxxx_SpacingMap:xxxxxxxx.GRID_SPACING_MAP&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4431&BBOX=1080020.71277404553256929,12232953.25763050653040409,1354911.23849608213640749,12477890.19503248669207096,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4431
 - server replied: Bad Request. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5'
```

The services pull data from ArcSDE, however I also tried from a File Geodatabase as a test and got the same results.

---

Ultimately I am trying to consume in Bentley.  I have been using other clients to try and debug, including QGIS, with more or less the same results.   ArcGIS Portal is the exception.   QGIS is version 2.18.

No complex features.   Just a simple polygon layer with around 300 features.   No transactions or editing.

Per ArcGIS Server documentation:
The WFS services you create are compliant with the WFS 1.1.0 and 2.0 specifications. They also support the WFS 1.0.0 specification on a read-only basis.

Comment: What version of QGIS did you use? What WFS versions are supported by your service? Is it a complex feature WFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug.

> Note in 10.3 the ObjectID is displayed, in 10.5 the ObjectID is
>   omitted. **BUG-000110388**: ObjectID and GlobalID fields are not
>   exposed in WFS services in ArcGIS server 10.5.x.
>
> There was an architecture change for WFS services at 10.5 release
>   which included many improvements to become WFS 2.0.0 compliant. At
>   10.5 design decision was made to use the gmlid as the primary key for WFS services, as according to OGC specification. Since gmlid is used
>   as the primary key, the old primary keys (objectid, globalid) are
>   filtered out. It is better practice to use the gmlid as the primary
>   key since it is required by all WFS services according to spec,
>   whereas the objectid field is an Esri specific field and not all WFS
>   services may have it.
>
> This defect brings awareness to the need of objectid/globalid fields
>   as they may play a critical role in third party platforms consuming
>   Esri WFS services. Fortunately, the defect is currently in our
>   production plan to be addressed in a future release. For updates,
>   please see the My Esri

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing this [bug](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDEwMjIzMA==).

Answer (score 0):

I found the that the problem with my WFS feed in ArcGIS Pro can be fixed by changing the x/y axis order as explained at this link.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/services/use-wfs-services.htm
 I don't readily see an answer for ArcMap.